# cannot decode valid json format, The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, object

I hav a valid json format `{"active":"false","period":"23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017","percentage":null,"value":null,"status":"inc","fixed_price":null}` but, when I tried to decode it, it return error

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

am I missing something?

Comment: I confirm this is a valid json. Maybe you are calling the decoder incorrectly.
Could you post the corresponding java code?

Comment: wrap your json function in `'` as a result use `$json = '{"active":"false","period":"23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017","percentage":null,"value":null,"status":"inc","fixed_price":null}'` . Pay attention to openning and closing. then you can call `json_decode($json)`

Comment: i use php json _decoder. I save that string in a variable then call this `json_decoder($a)` . Then error happened @Elektordi

Comment: Already did that, it returns the same error @PeymanSeraj

Comment: Can you show a little of your code? Do you get the result from a third server ? if yes can you dd($result) and show us the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your json function in `'` . as a result use `$json = '{"active":"false","period":"23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017","percentage":null,"value":null,"status":"inc","f‌​ixed_price":null}'` .

Pay attention to openning and closing. then you can call json_decode($json)

here is the complete result in artisan tinker:

```
>>> $json = '{"active":"false","period":"23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017","percentage":null,"value":null,"status":"inc","fixed_price":null}'
=> "{"active":"false","period":"23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017","percentage":null,"value":null,"status":"inc","fixed_price":null}"
>>> json_decode($json);
=> {#869
 +"active": "false",
 +"period": "23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017",
 +"percentage": null,
 +"value": null,
 +"status": "inc",
 +"fixed_price": null,
   }
```

Comment: idk why but, when I call a function `example(return json_decode('{"active":"false","period":"23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017","percentage":null,"value":null,"status":"inc","f‌​ixed_price":null}'))` it gives an error, but when I call it like this `$result = example(return json_decode('{"active":"false","period":"23-05-2017 to 25-05-2017","percentage":null,"value":null,"status":"inc","f‌​ixed_price":null}'))` it works.. Thankyou anyway

Comment: Is example your function? And you mean when you call it directly it does not works but when you store that inside a `$result` variable it works?

Comment: can you delete `return` and check again. `json_decode` is returning the result anyway without `return`. If you `dd(json_decode($json)` you should have the result. and it has no difference with `$result = json_decode($json)` and then `dd($result)`.